# Is there a resource that lists many of the different chess set styles?

Tags: chess-set

I know that there's the Staunton, Zagreb, and Dubrovnik style chess pieces which have seemingly been standardized.

It also seems that there's a common generic style of chess piece that I've seen in plastic, glass, and wood.

I just don't know the name of it.

I've searched and searched for a resource that would list the different piece styles (or at least the most common ones) but I only seem to be able to find short lists.

So is there a resource out there or does anyone know off hand what some of the different piece styles are?

Comment: FYI - I looked at the chess set options in the Chessmaster program, but the list is incomplete. It didn't have the Dubrovnik style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [The Illustrated Guide to World Chess Sets (Chessmen for Collectors)](http://www.historyofchess.co.uk/chessmen.htm) by [Dr Victor Keats](http://www.historyofchess.co.uk/author.htm)

A part from the books webpage:

> Country by country each chapter of Chessmen for Collectors
>   systematically charts the development of chess sets in chronological
>   order, giving the collector an instant means of identification. The
>   accompanying mass of illustrations (50 colour and 273 black and white)
>   gives details of the diverse materials used - ivory, wood, porcelain,
>   bronze - precise heights of pawns and pieces, their provenance and
>   date.

[image: Ivory Indian chessmen, chariots and juggernauts, late eighteenth century]

<sup>*Ivory Indian chessmen, chariots and juggernauts, late eighteenth century*</sup>

> Ivory Indian chessmen, chariots and juggernauts, late eighteenth
>   century The text and illustrations together highlight the variation of
>   style in English Staunton sets, Indian ivory sets, Spanish 'pulpit'
>   chessmen and delicate French eighteenth-century sets, as well as
>   highly unusual, 'one-off' sets from Africa and America. The whole
>   amounts to a highly authoritative, wide-ranging reference work for any
>   kind of chess collector.

---

### Other minor sources

This page lists some modern designs: http://inspirationfeed.com/inspiration/industrial-inspiration/20-aesthetic-chess-set-designs/

This online store has a lot of differently themed chess sets: https://www.chesshouse.com/collections/themed-chess-pieces